# Rebuild failed downstream project after upstream was build

Tags: jenkins

I'm currently having the following issue. I have to projects, P1 and P2. P2 is dependent from P1, so it is a downstream project of P1. Sometimes when pushing both P1 and P2, P2 fails building because P1 isn't built yet. Is it possible to rebuild a failed project if an upstream project has a new successful build?

Comment: Why do you trigger the downstream job from push? Would it not make more sense to only trigger upstream from push and if this finishes start the downstream job.?

Comment: @marxmacher Because not all downstream changes require upstream changes